# How could it be that a skewed distribution produces a small standard error (smaller than the standard error taken from two normal distributions)?

Tags: distributions, sampling, descriptive-statistics, standard-error, central-limit-theorem

I have three variables. Both Var1 and Var3 have approximately normal distributions, but Var2 has a right-skewed distribution (still fairly normal though).

**What I did:** I took 100 SRSWOR (n=250) from each variables and calculated the mean for each of the 100 samples. I then plotted the distribution of these sample means for each variable.

**I ended up getting the following distributions:**
[image: Distributions of estimated population means for each variable]

However, the standard error for each of these distributions is as follows:

```
> std(Var3mean)
[1] 18.35641
> std(Var2mean)
[1] 15.89423
> std(Var1mean)
[1] 18.11255
```

How could it be that the standard error for Var2 is the smallest, even though when you look at the distribution of its estimated population means it appears to have the most variable sample means out of the three?

Comment: This does not allow much discussion as you don't show any concrete evidence for the original variables. Normal quantile plots are more helpful than histograms. Mean and SD for the original variables are more pertinent than skewness, although no harm in showing measures of skewness too.

Comment: You should follow the advice and tell us more details&context! But: Why are you surprised? The normal distribution is maximizing entropy among distributions with given variance --- so non-normality among otherwise similar distributions could well mean lower variance (hence standard error of means based on the same sample size.)

Comment: The SE depends on the variance, while the skewness has nothing to do with the variance.  Therefore there doesn't look like much explanation is required.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done here is given additional evidence of the problems of using histograms. As William S. Cleveland said

> The histogram is a widely used graphical method that is at least a
>   century old. But maturity and ubiquity do not guarantee the efficacy
>   of a tool. The histogram is a poor method of comparing groups of
>   univariate measurements.

Visualizing Data, p. 8

Look at your 3 histograms:

1. They have different bin widths (they are the same numerically but different physically because of 2.)
2. They have different ranges.
3. The y axes are not identically scaled
4. Despite your assertion that

> when you look at the distribution of its estimated population means it
>   appears to have the most variable sample means

it doesn't look that way to me.  var 2 has far fewer cases in the extreme bins.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this, but I see consistent bin width of 100 in the original histograms.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they are the same numerical width, but different physical widths.  

More confusion caused by histograms!